# Yii core messages translation

Tags: internationalization, yii, translation

I want to translate yii core english messages to my language. But I can't find file with original (english) messages to translate. Where can I find this file or how to get latest english messages to translate?

Answer (score 1):

the file is framework/messages/de/yii.php

you can find details of how to customise it [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/18/how-to-customize-yii-core-messages/)